# web-api dont changes objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a method with Web Api and entity framework with SQL Server 2012

```
[Route("api/ptemployees")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
var employees = EmployeesRepository.GetAllEmployees();
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employees);
return response;
}

public class EmployeesRepository
{
private static ProjectTrackingDBEntities dataContext = new ProjectTrackingDBEntities();
public static List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
{
var query = from employee in dataContext.Employees
select employee;
return query.ToList();
}
}
```

and use to serialize json the data that server retrieve.

the problem is that if I upgrade to a different id field from Managment Studio (EmployeeName), 
the changes are not reflected in the json objects to give browser refresh the EmployeeName field not change, maintaining a cache!

Any idea? help.

Comment: Can you post the body of Employee class, and your Employee DB schema

Comment: I found the solution to this problem. The variable ProjectTrackingDBEntities  must not be static , I've instantiated again within the method GetAllEmployees and problem solved !